Removing spaces from a string in SQL
In my database I have a string that looks like this "P1_123456".
I am splitting the P1_ from the rest with the following:
right([PersNr], charindex('_', reverse([PersNr])) - 1) as PersNr

That leaves me with a single "space" after the last number. How can I prevent that space or remove it? I know how to remove spaces normally but not in combination with what I already have.

Check if the column PersNr itself has any leading and trailing whitespaces in the data. Moreover, you can use LTRIM(RTRIM(RIGHT([PersNr], CHARINDEX('_', REVERSE([PersNr])) - 1))) AS PersNr to trim those left and right unnecessary spaces.

replace(value, ' ', '')?

There is no space left in the example you are showing? https://dbfiddle.uk/zw27oDlE Please provide a [mre].

If there are simple spaces then RTRIM(PersNr) like
Right( RTrim( PersNr ), Charindex( '_', Reverse( RTrim( PersNr )) -1 ) 

will work. However if there are trailing non breaking spaces ( Dec 160 instead of 32 ) then Replace is first required.
Alternative to optimise performance can be
Rtrim( Right( PersNr, Charindex( '_', Reverse( PersNr ) -1 ))

However if this extraction is necessary to generate a criteria (that goes into a WHERE clause) the better way is an Inline Table Value Function.
If this is the case, please provide a new question with full reproducible data set. Or read up on ITVFs.

you can use RTRIM() function to remove trailing spaces, combining it with your original query. It looks like this
RTRIM(right([PersNr], charindex('_', reverse([PersNr])) - 1)) as PersNr


That's identical to the same existing, accepted answer, just without the helpful explanation. What does your answer add that isn't already provided?
